# How to set up rosjava classpath?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a downloaded rosjava package for using april tags.  I have installed the deb install of ros-hydro-rosjava.  However, when I run catkin_create_rosjava_pkg, I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'april'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:gradle_plugins:[0.1,0.2).
     Required by:
         :april:unspecified
```

What have I failed to set up?  is catkin_create_rosjava_pkg even the right thing to be running here?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131556/how-to-set-up-rosjava-classpath?/) by [gtaylor](https://answers.ros.org/users/12281/gtaylor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-03-15**:
What are the april tags? Are you downloading all rosjava sources into a source workspace with your project, or using the debs?

**Comment by [gtaylor](https://answers.ros.org/users/12281/gtaylor/) on 2014-03-15**:
Thank you for the responses. Daniel, APRIL Tags can be found here: http://april.eecs.umich.edu/wiki/index.php/AprilTags

Time ran out on getting this to work. I never did figure out how to get the rosjava classpaths set up correctly, even with the deb install, but it's no longer so relevant.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-03-16**:
Ok. Apologies for not getting back to you  more quickly, it looks like a trivial issue related to setting up your workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, almost certainly it's something silly.  Thanks, anyway.

---

Originally posted by [gtaylor](https://answers.ros.org/users/12281/gtaylor/) with karma: 16 on 2014-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0